# Arel: Left outer join using symbols

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have this use case where I get the symbolized deep associations from a certain model, and I have to perform certain queries that involve using outer joins. How can one do it WITHOUT resorting to write the full SQL by hand?

Answers I don't want:
- using includes (doesn't solve deep associations very well ( .includes(:cars => [:windows, :engine => [:ignition]..... works unexpectedly ) and I don't want its side-effects)
- writing the SQL myself (sorry, it's 2013, cross-db support, etc etc..., and the objects I fetch are read_only, more side-effects)

I'd like to have an Arel solution. I know that using the arel_table's from the models I can construct SQL expressions, there's also a DSL for the joins, but somehow i cannot use it in the joins method from the model:

```
car = Car.arel_table
engine = Engine.arel_table

eng_exp = car.join(engine).on(car[:engine_id].eq(engine[:id]))
eng_exp.to_sql #=> GOOD! very nice!
Car.joins(eng_exp) #=> Breaks!!
```

Why this doesn't work is beyond me. I don't know exactly what is missing. But it's the closest thing to a solution I have now. If somebody could help me completing my example or provide me with a nice work-around or tell me when will Rails include such an obviously necessary feature will have my everlasting gratitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a blog post that purports to address this problem: http://blog.donwilson.net/2011/11/constructing-a-less-than-simple-query-with-rails-and-arel/

Based on this (and my own testing), the following should work for your situation:

```
car = Car.arel_table
engine = Engine.arel_table   

sql = car.project(car[Arel.star])
        .join(engine, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(car[:engine_id].eq(engine[:id]))

Car.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: Well, this is the closest to the answer we'll ever get, I'm afraid, my only problem with being the previous knowledge of the association keys (I would like to have a more out-of-the-box solution concerning that, like the plain regular AR inner joins). But this is by far the best answer to the question, I already devised a solution based on it. Thx again.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone finding it through search engines:

If you want something you can pass into `.joins`, you can either use `.create_join` and `.create_on`:

```
join_on = car.create_on(car[:engine_id].eq(engine[:id]))
eng_join = car.create_join(engine, join_on, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)

Car.joins(eng_join)
```

OR

use the `.join_sources` from your constructed join object:

```
eng_exp = car.join(engine, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(car[:engine_id].eq(engine[:id]))
Car.joins(eng_exp.join_sources)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a dependency and skipping AREL altogether, you could use [Ernie Miller's excellent Squeel gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#joins). It would be something like

```
Car.joins{engine.outer}.where(...)
```

This would require that the Car model be associated with Engine like so:

```
belongs_to :engine
```