# Ransack error when sorting by joined table attribute: table name "users" specified more than once

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ransack

When clicking on the table header to sort by `user_email`(see view), the query it tries to run (see console output) has a duplicate `left join users on users.id = invites.user_id`.

That appears to be causing the problem, but how to avoid it I'm not sure.

**Error:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::Invites#index
PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "users" specified more than once
```

**Console Output:**

```
: SELECT  
    invites.id,
    invites.email,
    users.id as user_id,
    users.email as user_email FROM "invites" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "invites"."user_id" 
  left join users on users.id = invites.user_id 
  ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2):
```

**Controller**

```
@q = query.ransack(params[:q])
@invites = @q.result.page params[:page]
```

**`query` method called by controller**

```
def query
  Invite.select('invites.id,
                 invites.email,
                 users.id as user_id,
                 users.email as user_email')
  .joins('left join users on users.id = invites.user_id')
end
```

**View**

```
<th><%=sort_link(@q, :email, 'Sendee Email') %></th>
<th><%=sort_link(@q, :user_email, 'Sender Email') %></th>
```

I'm trying Ransack for the first time (and it's awesome), but I would love to avoid this error somehow.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

### UPDATE

> {"s"=>"user_email asc"},
>   "controller"=>"admin/invites", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :email, 'Sendee Email') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :user_email, 'Accepted') %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @invites.each do |i| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= i.email %></td>
        <td><%= i.user_email %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

...

Comment: Hello, could you add how `params` look, it looks like `ransack` adds an extra join that you don't need

Comment: Updated above - `params` that #index receives. Its weird that it only errors  when sorting by `user_email` from the associated `User` model, but works when sorting by attributes from `Invite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `.joins('left join users on users.id = invites.user_id')`, you need to change/remove it because it always adds a join to your `SQL` even when it'a not needed - [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#grouping-queries-by-or-instead-of-and) is smart enough to figure out when do the join based on params you pass to `ransack`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029652/arel-left-outer-join-using-symbols) may help you, you have to rewrite `query` method

First Scenario

```
{"s"=>"email asc"}, "controller"=>"admin/invites", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

generated SQL

```
SELECT  
  invites.id,
  invites.email,
  users.id as user_id,
  users.email as user_email FROM "invites" 
left join users on users.id = invites.user_id 
ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2)
```

one JOIN - SQL is ok

Second Scenario

```
{"s"=>"user_email asc"}, "controller"=>"admin/invites", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

generated SQL

```
SELECT  
  invites.id,
  invites.email,
  users.id as user_id,
  users.email as user_email FROM "invites" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "invites"."user_id" 
left join users on users.id = invites.user_id 
ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2)
```

two JOINs - SQL is bad

Comment: But I need the original join to display `users.email` in my list view. I could be wrong, but I don't see how else my list view could display `users.email` when not sorting...?

Comment: There are 2 columns, which display `invites.email` and `users.email`. The .html.erb I posted above under `View` are the `<th>` tags for the column headers - just added the `<th>` tags to my question.

Comment: Added the bigger block of html now.

Comment: you can change `<td><%= i.user_email %></td>` to `<td><%= i.user.email %></td>` this will eliminate the need for the join